# Download multiple files from a website instantly

Tags: download

There is this website called Texture Haven, which has a lot of free textures to use for blender, only problem is it takes a lot of work to download them all manually.

So my question is: Would there be a way to download them all instantly with some kind of script?

Texture Haven: https://texturehaven.com/textures/

Comment: Have you tried something already by yourself? Good starting points would be python modules like `beautifulsoup` or `scrapy`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking for web-downloaders with Python? I'm not sure if it will work but you can try some of these: 
1. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/downloading-files-web-using-python/ 
2. https://pypi.org/project/pywebcopy/ 
3. https://www.codementor.io/aviaryan/downloading-files-from-urls-in-python-77q3bs0un

Let me know if this works out for you. Otherwise you'll just have to manually download the packages. You could also try out other websites for blender textures like:

- https://texture.ninja/ not sure if you can install entire packages at once but it's fairly easy to install lot's of textures.

You could also look for some add-ons for blender like https://www.blenderkit.com/

I hope this works out for you and happy blending!

Edit: format

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide some code to your answer?